# why doesn't mybatis-generate rootclass work?

Tags: mybatis-generator

I try to use mybatis-generate to generate entity and use rootclass to let the generator entities to extend the BaseEntity.

```
public class BaseEntity{
     private Long id;
     getter and setter...
}
```

But after I run mybatis-generate,the properties in BaseEntity are override in child entities，like:

```
public class User extend BaseEntity{
   private Long Id;
   other properties and getters and setters...
}
```

The Id property should not appear in User classs,because there is an Id property in BaseEntity.
and my configration of rootClass in gengerator-config.xml is :

```
<javaModelGenerator targetPackage="${mybatis.type-aliases-package}"
                        targetProject="${target.project}">
    <property name="rootClass" 
     value="site.bigbear.classmate.party.pojo.BaseEntity"/>
</javaModelGenerator>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Post your error

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya.There is no error.Mybatis-generator run success.The problem is that the subclass should not override properties in the parent class (such as the Id property) after the mybatis-generatortor is run.

Comment: There should be warnings in the generator's output.  Probably your BaseEntity is not in the Generator's classpath so it can't find the class and introspect it.

Comment: @JeffButler can we use MBG generated class as rootClass ?